# Java Spring Boot Project without pom.xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, gradle

I am new to spring boot project. Recently I was requested to add new functionalities to a spring boot project. I was given the source code of the project. Surprisingly, the pom.xml was missing in the project structure. Moreover, lib directory is missing. Not external .jar were provided.

How can I know the required version and suitable jar files without the pom.xml?

I was trying to add some related spring jar files, but unfortunately I can't run the spring application.
Here's the error message:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.0.RELEASE)

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.abc.abcXmlApiService.abcxmlapiserviceApplication]; nested exception is org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'emailValidator' for bean class [com.abc.web.validator.EmailValidator] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [com.abc.admin.web.validator.EmailValidator]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:181)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:315)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:232)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:705)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:61)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234)
    at com.abc.abcXmlApiService.abcxmlapiserviceApplication.main(abcxmlapiserviceApplication.java:25)
Caused by: org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'emailValidator' for bean class [com.abc.web.validator.EmailValidator] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [com.abc.admin.web.validator.EmailValidator]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.checkCandidate(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:348)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:286)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanAnnotationParser.parse(ComponentScanAnnotationParser.java:132)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:287)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:242)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:199)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:167)
    ... 13 more
```

Comment: Most likely the project uses Gradle instead of Maven. Is there a `build.gradle` file?

Comment: lib directory is missing ... a lib directory isn't mandatory, nor required.

Comment: There should not be a lib directory at all. Without a POM or build.gradle you cannot progress on this project. If there is no build file for maven or gradle you're screwed and need to talk to your manager.

Comment: @Jeroen Steenbeeke There are no any gradle build script (build.gradle) exist.

Comment: How about `build.xml` (Ant) or `ivy.xml` (Apache Ivy)? Bit of a long shot considering this is a Spring Boot project so I wouldn't expect anything other than Maven or Gradle

Comment: @Software Engineer
I have talked to my product manager and he replied me that project is missing the pom or build gradle (any build script). So it is impossible for me to process the project with the pom/build.gradle? One of my colleague suggests me to try adding different version of spring boot related jar manually by downloading them from mvnrepository.com
I have already tried different versions but none of them works.

Comment: You shouldn't add any jars manually. You can try to recreate the pom and guess the libs/versions based on the error messages. But, unless this is a relatively trivial application you're facing anuphill struggle to find the right libs, and you might not succeed. The right course of action is to say 'no' to maintaining unacceptably poor code and have your organisation react to having this toxic-asset on their books by improving their standards and QA. If you fix it for them they'll probably not acknowledge the problems it has caused and will not be given the chance to improve.

Comment: @Software Engineer Thanks for your genuine advice. We are contacting the resigned colleague who created the project for further info. Thanks all of the advices above.

Answer (score -1):

The error message `Caused by: org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'emailValidator' for bean class [com.abc.web.validator.EmailValidator] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [com.abc.admin.web.validator.EmailValidator]` clearly indicates, `emailValidator` duplicates in your project, please cross check the name if any duplicates.